# How can I click on a picture and then make that picture appear in a new JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

I have a JFrame opening with 12 different pictures. I want to click on one and then in the new JFrame, show that same picture. In my code, shirts is my JFrame with the 12 pictures and I want the clicked picture to appear in the new JFrame called sizes. I made an ArrayList of type JLabel called select. Here is my code:

```
final JFrame shirts = new JFrame("T-shirts");

          JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4, 3, 3));

          for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
            l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("T-shirts/"+i+".jpg"), JLabel.CENTER);

            l.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
            l.setFont(l.getFont().deriveFont(20f));
            panel.add(l);
            select.add(l);
          }//end of for loop

          panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
              sizes = new JFrame("Shopping");
              sizes.setVisible(true);
              sizes.setSize(500, 500);
              sizes.setLocation(100,200);
              shirts.dispose();


            for(int i=0; i<12; i++){
                if(e.getSource()==select.get(i)){
            JLabel addition = newJLabel(newImageIcon(select.get(i).getText()));
                  //sizes.add(select.get(i));//Picture isn't added!!
               }//end of if

            }//end of for
            }//end of method  
          });//end of listener


          shirts.setContentPane(panel);
          shirts.setSize(1000, 1000);
          shirts.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          shirts.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: [Possibly Relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/1702990)

Comment: [Also quite relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29735247/522444)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  By 'relevant' DYM 'duplicate'?  I can't see the  difference between the two.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Yep, I didn't see that it was the same person asking these questions. Nothing like having your answer ignored to motivate you to help the guy again. Closing this question as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `JButton` and make it look like a `JLabel`:

```
JButton button = new JButton( new ImageIcon("..." ));
button.setBorderPainted( false );
button.setContentFilled( false );
button.setFocusPainted( false );
button.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
        Icon icon = button.getIcon();
        // do something with the Icon.
    }
});
```

Then you can add an `ActionListener` to the button.

An `ActionListener` is more reliable than using a `MouseListener` and handling the `mouseClicked` event. The `mouseClicked` event is only generated when a `mousePressed` and `mouseReleased` event is generated at the same mouse point. So if the mouse moves by even pixel between the two event you will not get a `mouseClicked` event which users think is a random problem.

Comment: Yes, I suggested this to the OP two days ago on their [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29735016/418556)..  :-/  You can lead a horse to water..

Comment: @AndrewThompson, thanks for the heads up. Three questions on this topic.... and counting. Won't be so quick to help the next time a question is posted.

Answer (score 3):

Start with [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html).

Basically, you want to register a `MouseListener` with the `JLabel` which represents your picture and implement it's `mouseClicked` method.

You then want to get the `Icon` property of the `JLabel` that was clicked and pass that to your new frame, which you can simply use to set the `Icon` property of another `JLabel`

Something like...

```
addition.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        JLabel label = (JLabel) e.getComponent();
        Icon icon = label.getIcon();
        // Create new frame and pass it the icon value
    }

});
```

as an example

You might also like to take a look at [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) and consider using either a `CardLayout` or `JDialog` instead of another `JFrame` ... which could become messy

Comment: How do you pass the icon to the JFrame?

Comment: [Like you pass any object to any constructor or method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try making each picture a JButton, or at least placing an invisible button behind each picture. Then, when they are pressed in the ActionListener extended class, have the new JFrame be created, with the picture large.